# lucene indexer stopped without complete the whole files

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search built on top of Lucene indexing to deal with text files existing in MySQL database. The hibernate search version 4.1.1, lucene version 3.5.0 and MySQL version 5.6  . All functions that I need was working well(search , indexing ... etc). Recently, I moved the same code, libraries, and database to another server with bigger hard disk and RAM.

The problem is the lucene indexer stopped without complete the whole files without any warning or errors. what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check if it hasn't finished already? If the new machine is large enough to be able to cache everything in memory, it might be able to reindex everything very quickly.

Comment: I'm sure. I'm using Luke to browse the index files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from the database, some records have foreign keys were already deleted from the origin table. I deleted these records and problem solved.